# Rspec: controller spec login helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, rspec

I am using **rspec** to test my controllers. The problem is that I need a login helper method every other controller tests will use in its `before(:each) do` method.

Right now, I am testing **ReportsController** just getting its *index* action.

```
RSpec.describe ReportsController, type: :controller do
    let(:user) {build :user, :storeadmin}

    before(:each) do
      @request.host = "localhost:3000"
      login(user) if session[:id].blank?
    end

    # Index action has different types of responses
    describe "#index" do
      context "when content-type html" do  
        before do
          get :index
        end
        it { expect(response.content_type).to eq "text/html"}
        it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok) }        
      end
   end
end
```

My Helper:

```
def login(user)    
    post login_submit_path, {admin:{login_id:user.login_id, password: user.password}}     
end
```

When I execute my test it posts to **ReportsController**'s *login* not **LoginController**'s *login*. And it fails because of `:before_filter` which checks if the user is logged in using session. I have also tried directly setting session inside my helper method e.g `request.session[:user] = user from db` and `session[:user]=user from db`.

Comment: What authorisation system do you use? Also you can skip before filter (controller.class.skip_before_filter :name_of_method_used_as_before_filter) and directly setup current_user

Comment: None. Using role constraints in the routes.rb

Comment: Can you show you login controller and routes.rb?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response guys. I solved it using `request.session` wherever I am using sessions.